# Postgres. Split string field separated by comma to new columns

Tags: postgresql, split, migration

I have a table that looks like
that

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Value1,Value2,Value3 |

What I need to do is to create an extra column for the "values" and copy them to the new rows
What's the best approach to tackle the task?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create an array and unnest this array to create different records. Something like this:

```
SELECT  unnest(string_to_array('Value1,Value2,Value3', ','));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres 14 or later you can use `string_to_table()`

```
select t.id, x.code
from the_table t
  cross join string_to_table(code, ',') as x(code)
```

For older version use the combination of `string_to_array()` and `unnest()`.